# Call google analytics method _trackEvent() from php

Tags: php, google-analytics, php-5.3

I need to call the methode _trackEvent() from php when execute a route. It's possible to do that in php ? Help me please. Exist a solution. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

_trackEvent is a) Javascript and b) deprecated. So you can't call it from php, but you can use the Google measurement protocol to get the same results.

The measurement protocol is a standard API that now forms the basis for data collection for Universal Analytics (across all devices). You specify a client id and a hit type (in your case "event") and some necessary parameters depending on your hit type.

The API endpoint is `www.google-analytics.com/collect`. The parameter list for an event looks like this:

```
v=1             // Version.
&tid=UA-XXXX-Y  // Tracking ID / Property ID.
&cid=555        // Anonymous Client ID.
&t=event        // Event hit type
&ec=eventCategory       // Event Category. Required.
&ea=evenAction        // Event Action. Required.
&el=eventLabel     // Event label.
&ev=1         // Event value.
```

This example uses placeholders (so replace the values after the equal sign with you own variables), event label and event value is optional. Send the url with parameters via POST (per documentation, actually a GET works, too), via  curl or fopen or whatever when executing your route.

The example is from the [documentation here.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#event)

Answer (score 0):

The lazy thing to do (if your having problems) is not to bother, you can always post from ajax to google or back to your sever.

If you really want to look into full integration with analytics, the doc's are here 
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-php.